# Infimum of a set with two variables

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have encountered a problem concerning the infimum of a set:

Prove that. $$\mathrm {inf} \left\lbrace\sqrt{a^2+{1\over b^2}}:a,b\in(0,1) \right\rbrace=1$$

What I've been able to do is to prove that: $$\mathrm{inf}\left\lbrace a^2:a\in(0,1) \right\rbrace=0$$
and $$\mathrm{inf}\left\lbrace {1\over{b^2}}:b\in(0,1) \right\rbrace=1$$
combining these two results bearing in mind that $\sqrt1=1$ I've concluded that the above equation holds. However my approach doesn't seem rigorous enough.
Could someone give me hint or an advice on how to refine my proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just take the infimum over $a$ and $b$ separately.
The correct proof goes something like this:

Since $a>0$, $0<b<1$, we have,
$$\sqrt{a^2+\frac{1}{b^2}}> \frac{1}{b} > 1$$

so the infimum is $\ge 1$. Now you are done, if you can choose a sequence $a_n,b_n\in (0,1)$ such that $\sqrt{a_n^2+\frac{1}{b_n^2}}\rightarrow 1$ (why? and do that).

Comment: A sequence? I think *two* sequences.

Comment: A sequence of pairs, yes :P.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it suffices to take for instance: $a_n={1\over n}$ and $b_n={n\over n+1}$ and let $n\to\infty$ to show that the members of the above set can get arbitrarily close to $1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just take the inf over 2 variables separately, but the fact they can be chosen independently means this is good working.

To show that $1$ is the greatest lower bound. You can see it's a lower bound as that quantity always bigger than $1$.

Then to show it's the biggest, you can show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $1 + \epsilon$ isn't a lower bound (any greater lower bound could be written in this form). You can do this choosing $0<a<1$ really close to $0$ and $0<b<1$ really close to 1 to get $\sqrt{a^2 + 1/b^2}$ less than $1+\epsilon$. You may find it useful to note that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq |x| + |y|$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, and since $\;0<a,b<1\;$ (*)

$$\sqrt{a^2+\frac1{b^2}}=\frac1b\sqrt{a^2b^2+1}\ge 1\iff a^2b^2+1\ge b^2\iff b^2(1-a^2)\le 1$$

and the last inquality follows from (*), as $\;0<b^2\,,\,1-a^2<1\;$.

On the other hand, whenever $\;a\to 0\;$ and $\;b\to 1\;$ , we get that $\;\sqrt{a^2+\frac1{b^2}}\to 1\;$